# How to make clickable popover disappear if I clicked outside of it

Tags: javascript, html, css, laravel-blade, popover

I have this popover contain some info and URL to another page so when I clicked on it it's open, but when I click outside of it it won't disappear,

```
`<i class="bi bi-question-circle text-primary float-right" data-bs-toggle="popover" data-bs-content="{{$accountTypeQuestionMark[$value] ? $accountTypeQuestionMark[$value]:''}}" data-bs-trigger="click"  data-bs-html="true" ></i>
`
```

and this the JavaScript for it:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var popoverTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="popover"]'))
        var popoverList = popoverTriggerList.map(function (popoverTriggerEl) {
        return new bootstrap.Popover(popoverTriggerEl)
    })
</script>
```

I tried using this code but it didn't work:

````
$(document).on('click', function (e) {
    $('[data-bs-toggle="popover"]').each(function () {
        if (!$(this).is(e.target) && $(this).has(e.target).length === 0 && $('.popover').has(e.target).length === 0) {
            $(this).popover('hide');
        }
    });
});```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are gonna have to make these changes in your popover for this functionality:
`tabindex="0"` and change `data-bs-trigger` to `focus`. And in the end, it will look like this:

```
<i class="bi bi-question-circle text-primary float-right" tabindex="0" data-bs-toggle="popover" data-bs-content="{{$accountTypeQuestionMark[$value] ? $accountTypeQuestionMark[$value]:''}}" data-bs-trigger="focus"  data-bs-html="true" >Click here for popover</i>
```

```js
var popoverTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="popover"]'))
    var popoverList = popoverTriggerList.map(function (popoverTriggerEl) {
    return new bootstrap.Popover(popoverTriggerEl)
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<i class="bi bi-question-circle text-primary float-right" tabindex="0" data-bs-toggle="popover" data-bs-content="{{$accountTypeQuestionMark[$value] ? $accountTypeQuestionMark[$value]:''}}" data-bs-trigger="focus"  data-bs-html="true" >Click here for popover</i>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```